# append text to href using sed

Tags: sed

I have the following links in a file file.html

```
href="Getting_started.html"
href="Authentication.html" and many more.
```

I want these links to be written as

```
href="/docs/Getting_started.html"
href="/docs/Authentication.html"
```

So I have used below command

```
sed -i 's/href=\"/href="\/docs\//g' file.html
```

**My question** : is there any other better way to perform the same task or there is no harm in running this command?

Comment: simply change the separator `/` to `|` - run it first without `-i` to check if its ok - `sed -i 's|href="|href="/docs/|g' file.html`

Comment: The command will work well for the task you explain. But we cannot see if there is harm running this command as we don't know what other content is in your `file.html`. There might be a better way doing this with a dedicated XML parser, or python+beautifulsoup, but with the information given `sed` is just fine...